# How to hide intermediate values of a long computation?

Tags: r, scope

I am learning R.

I need to do a complex computation, producing a single number. For readability, I split it into parts. Because I don't want to pollute the global namespace, I use a dummy function:

```
global <- somevalue  # I know globals are a horrid practice
foo <- function()
{
    a <- some complex computation
    b <- other complex or at least long formulas

    a + b  # result
}
res <- foo()
```

This feels wrong for several reasons:

- I am still polluting with `foo()`
- there is too much boilerplate

One solution would be to use a pipe, but I don't want to, because the variable names are expressive and important.

In C++ I would have used an immediately invoked function expression:

```
const auto res = [&global] () { /*compute, compute*/; return a + b; } ();
```

How to cleanly compute an end value in R, while hiding intermediate results?

Comment: You could try the `local` function. E.g. `res <- local({a <- 1; b <- 2; return(a+b)})`. That way you are not creating a function in the global environment. Also, `a` and `b` are not created in the global environment.

Comment: @MikeH. you should post this as an answer - it could be the best one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to try using the `local` function. This way you don't have to make a function or store intermediate variables in the global environment:

```
res <- local({a <- 1
              b <- 2
              return(a+b)})
```